# Empty pages in the compiled PDF

Tags: emptypage

I am new to Latex and I am using it to write my thesis. I have this problem where if I use this line of code:

```
\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{\newpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}}
```

all my chapters start with a new page, however, I get empty pages in between two chapters). Whereas when I comment it out chapters get mixed together. For example conclusion of chapter 2 and the Intro of chapter 3 are written in the same page.

Is there a workaround to this ? I want each chapter to start with a new page with no empty pages.

Comment: if defining that command does anything then you must be _using_ it somewhere, so if you just comment out the definition you will get errors.  In most book level classes the default is that chapters always start on right hand (odd) pages, so you will get a blank even page if the previous chapter ends on an odd page. the purpose of the command you show is to make that blank page completely empty with the page number not printed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the intel ! So is there any way to get rid of these blank pages?

Comment: If you indeed use the  book class, adding openany as a class option might be helpful.

Comment: You have given _no clues_ what your input looks like, but in most classes `openany` option if you want to allow chapters to open on the left or `oneside` if you do not want separately styled left and right pages, but really the blank pages are not a problem to be solved, they are the result of a few hundred years of typesetting tradition.